# Magnetic Field Sensor?

Tags: sensor

I'm looking for a sensor that can detect large magnetic fields.  Basically, I want a 1 when the field is greater than 75 Gauss, and a 0 when it's less than 75 Gauss.

I believed (EDIT: Wrongly!) Hall Effect sensors rely on moving through a magnetic field.  <s>Unfortunately, my application does not permit me to move through the field, and the field is not changing.</s>  It's since been pointed out that the Hall Effect does not rely on a change in the magnetic field.  However, I still do not have any control over the orientation of the field.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to detect such a magnetic field?

Comment: as i put, 2 sensors will detect a field in any direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Allegro A1301](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/1301/) is a cheap analogue hall effect sensor. It's a 3 pin device: 5V GND and OUT. It outputs 2.5mV per Gauss detected.

It's very easy to use, [here's a project I used it in](http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/04/04/541/).

Comment: Thanks!  That's perfect, and will hook up just fine to an ADC input.  It looks like Allegro has a nice collection of sensors...they even have a PWM one that might work well with a PIC.

Comment: FYI, I settled on the A1362; programmable sensitivity up to 16 mV/Gauss (I guess 75 Gauss isn't as large as I thought it would be!), and a filter pin to constrain bandwidth/noise

Answer (score 6):

The Hall effect doesn't depend on variations in the magnetic field (i.e., motion relative to the field or time-varying field), as far as I know, it only depends on the strength of the field, and the orientation relative to the sensor.

Alternately you could look into 'magnetic reed switches'.

Comment: hall effect does not need motion.

Answer (score 3):

A hall effect sensor can detect large magnetic fields relatively easily. This is done by measuring the variance in resistance. You allow a DC current to pass, the Magnetic field will deflect electrons, increasing the DC resistance.

This gives you a magnetic field dependent resistor. These will be able to measure the current in 2 planes, the path of the current will be unaffected by a magnetic field in it's direction.

If you need to measure in 3 directions, I would suggest 2 to detect magnitude of field, and a general idea of direction. With 3 you can get a rather precise idea of direction.

There is no motion of the sensor required.

Comment: You're right, I will need more than one to calculate the field intensity.  I may be able to make an assumption about how the field *won't* be oriented, so I may be able to do with two axes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you want it to both turn off and on at 75 Gauss?  Magnetic fields are variable, and you might get a lot of noise at that edge.  Most Hall effect switches are designed with Hysteresis, or a [Schmitt Trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger), for this reason.

With this knowledge, you can start looking at [Digikey's selection of magnetic sensors](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=1967232).

The [Allegro A3295](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/3295/) is an example of such a device.  It turns on at 75 Gauss, and turns off once the field decays to 5 Gauss.

Comment: You're right, hysteresis is good, but I think I actually want a linear hall effect sensor so I can do it in software.

Answer (score -2):

LOL 75 Gauss means never having to say your circuit failed; the electrons in there aren't going in any loop the magnet didn't pick first! Pick an optical sensor (e.g. a mineral anvil or mirror, or more easily a simple F/O loop) and remotely detect changes in light transmission and polarization to confirm the field characteristics. Are you making bets with http://www.magnet.fsu.edu/ , installing your first maglev train, or just in charge of field cleaning COTS naval artillery? I knew One Piece was popular, but not maglev trains....

Comment: Er what? Are you confusing Gauss with Tesla? 75 Tesla would be a lot. E.G. the Magnet Lab managed to get 100 Tesla which was an amazing achievement. Achieving 75 Gauss means buying a couple of fridge magnets.